# adding polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Hello I dont know if this is the forum for this, if not just let me know and I'll delete the question.

I was pretty sure how to add polynomials until my teacher gave me this exercise and changed the $-7x$ of the first polynomial to $+7x$ and he wrote it like this..

$(3x^3 - 7x + 2) + (7x^2 + 2x -7)$

$(3x^3$ **`+ -`** $7x + 2) + (7x^2 + 2x $**`+ -`**$7)$

then he proceeded to allocate the "like terms" in horizontal descending, here is where he changes from negative to positive

$3x^3 + 7x^2 $ **`+`** $ 7x + 2x + 2 $**`+-`**$7$

and finally, he combined like terms

$3x^3 + 7x^2 + 9x -5$

He only wrote in this line

> express each subtraction like the sum of the opposites

I don't understand what he meant I thought when adding polynomials you don't change signs

Why he changed the $7x$ sign of the first polynomial?

**Edit**, here's a screen shot of the document the teacher sent us. Maybe i'm missing something...

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kO8f.png)

Comment: At first I would say that your teacher is trying to express that you are 'adding' the coefficients of $x^1=x$ (or $x^0=1$). But the second line makes no sense, and doesn't follow from the first either. Maybe you should ask him for clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. when he changes from negative to positive is when he was allocating like terms in horizontal descending, does this affect your answer? I edited my question.

Comment: You are right that this makes no sense. $(3x^3-7x+2)+(7x^2+2x-7)=3x^3+7x^2-5x-5$ and not $3x^3+7x^2+9x-5$. Could your professor have simply made a typo?

Comment: @YiFan I don't think so, he has other examples where he toggles signs when simplifying

Comment: Are you in an abstract algebra class? If so that could justify what he's doing; maybe he's working in some quotient of $\mathbb R[x]$. If not, then your professor is just wrong and you should clarify with him.

Comment: I feel that all he is trying to convey is fact that $a-b=a+(-b)$. This is useful and prevents confusion in many areas.

Comment: @Sam I thought so too at first, but the final result of $3x^3 + 7x^2 + 9x - 5$ is wrong. My bet is that one of either the prof or the OP made a transcription error here, nothing criminal.

Comment: Sam that would explain "Express each subtraction like the sum of the opposites" 
@nhmwhhxx I edited the question and posted a screen shot of  the exact document the teacher sent us. Mind that it is in spanish
YiFan no, its just plain old algebra

Comment: Likely a typo - maybe email him to check.

Comment: @nhmwhhxx I did, but he takes roughly a week to answer, oh well thanks anyways guys